# Lua: What's the math.btan2

Tags: lua

I'm very new in Lua.

I found a sepcial method named 'math.btan2(L, l, R, r)'when I read the Lua code. I can not find this method in any Lua document.

Can anybody tell me what is this method?

Thanks

Comment: Are you working on the crack of youku downloading url?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it. It would be much better if you can share me some more.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a function in 'bare' lua. It's either a user-defined function, or if the code is for Lua embedded in some platform it's a function provided by the platform.

There should be a `math.btan2` function definition in the file containing the code, or in the files that your code `require`s at its top. Such definition can begin with either of the following forms:

- `function math.btan2(the parameters)` ...
- `math.btan2 = function(the parameters)` ...

If not, search the platform documentation.

Comment: There is not any 'require' and definitions in the file. So maybe it's support by the platform. Does it supported in Android?

Comment: I don't have information about Lua ports on Android; if you are using a specific platform tag it to your question and it might attract more answers; however Google not returning any results shows this must be a user function. In Lua variables and functions can also be injected with `dofile` tricks from files calling the current file. Can you try searching inside all files in the project you're reading for "btan2"? It can be hidden in any place.

Answer (score 0):

You can find "btan2" in their libluajava.so file, so they have probably modified the luajava source code and added math.btan2 method by themselves.